# Find value inside several arrays and objects Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find a value inside nested arrays and json objects as shwon belwo. I mean i need to return the array that contain Geo=30 or IPSO = 9014 or Type =hum.

```
[
[],
[
    [
        {
            "id": "00bbdf70-f3b6-11e8-83e2-819217d5974f",
            "input": {
                "timestamp": 1543482365671,
                "amount": 500,
                "address": "04f269e492167c12959c83f8e4ceec55b008f812c390184258aeec88a47ba2b005fc3d2d50c6cc5e5d381accea75aa5dc7505ab0a096886a4542b06febae5f5e3c",
                "signature": {
                    "r": "c1ae00229088db266736849829807be71be81c8a5e7e340e675e6b308cefe99b",
                    "s": "3868173dfa3532fa78afcdc0d2d910762f608f82cf88661b044fb75c4769d1bf",
                    "recoveryParam": 0
                }
            },
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "amount": 50,
                    "address": "0401fe4624ebaa696dd6972376dca964a046439383f7faeb2cd46c76774c2d92e1a9492edbe44b0bd4c22469f7e6153b320eb4ae4deb73f4254fdc0d6660246252"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ID": "ff964b30-f3b5-11e8-83e2-819217d5974f",
            "Signiture": {
                "timestamp": 1543482363749,
                "address": "0401fe4624ebaa696dd6972376dca964a046439383f7faeb2cd46c76774c2d92e1a9492edbe44b0bd4c22469f7e6153b320eb4ae4deb73f4254fdc0d6660246252",
                "signature": {
                    "r": "451fa22ed213767326d4e1078aae4bb025446505897be909f604a2523110068b",
                    "s": "68c116d74ef17aab8c508e2f47443bc8074e2b4b595bd9316c8a652224cdecb9",
                    "recoveryParam": 1
                }
            },
            "Geo": 30,
            "IPSO": 9014,
            "Type": "hum",
            "Permission": "public",
            "OrgOwner": "none",
            "PrsnOwner": "0401fe4624ebaa696dd6972376dca964a046439383f7faeb2cd46c76774c2d92e1a9492edbe44b0bd4c22469f7e6153b320eb4ae4deb73f4254fdc0d6660246252",
            "MetaHash": "f6b6839817cdd3b02c4b421b0645f95ce9229c329ed52ee3be311681bc2de8b7",
            "SSNmetadata": [
                {
                    "@id": "_:genid1",
                    "@type": [
                        "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent"
                    ],
                    "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name": [
                        {
                            "@language": "en",
                            "@value": "W3C/OGC Spatial Data on the Web Working Group"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

]

I tried to return the array that contain (Geo=30)but i couldn't.

I tried many ways; the last one was this code but no responce

```
var e = lodash.find(bc.chain, function(o) {
 return lodash.some(o.data, function(Geo) {
 return Geo === 30;
 });
```

Comment: Try this it will work `_.filter(a, (o)=>_.find(o, {"Geo":30}));`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need top level array or array that actually contains the object (closest to object)? If nesting of arrays is not specified you may use recursion for this pruposes. Something like this:

```
findMatches(arr, {Geo: 30, Type: 'hum', IPSO: 9014});

function findMatches(source, conditionsOr) {
  if (Array.isArray(source)) {
    for (const item of source) {
      const match = findMatches(item, conditionsOr);

      if (Array.isArray(match)) {
        return match;  
      } else if (isObject(match)) {
        return item;
      }
    }
  } else if (isObject(source)) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(conditionsOr)) {
      if (source[key] === value) {
        return source;
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

function isObject(value) {
  return value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Object;
}
```